# Identifying if a Cell contains an equation in Word

Tags: python, excel, vba, ms-word

I have a table in Word filled with different texts, and some equations using Microsoft Equation 3.0.

I am currently trying to read the text from the table and create an Excel sheet with the same table.

Is there some way of normalizing the equations in Word into text?

If not, does somebody know how I can identify the equation to bypass it?

My current code for reading the table is this:

```
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False
raw_files = glob('*.docx')
xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
ss = xl.Workbooks.Add()
for f in raw_files:
    word.Documents.Open(f)
    doc = word.ActiveDocument
    for x in xrange(1, doc.Paragraphs.Count+1):
        oText = doc.Paragraphs(x)
        if oText.Range.Tables.Count >0 :
            ph = ss.ActiveSheet
            for r in xrange(1, oText.Range.Tables(1).Rows.Count):
                for c in xrange(1, oText.Range.Tables(1).Columns.Count):
                    if oText.Range.Tables(1).Cell(r,c).Range.Text != None:
                        ph.Cells(r+2,c).Value = oText.Range.Tables(1).Cell(r,c).Range.Text
```

The error when I run into the equation is 'The requested member does not exist.'

Is there an easy way to bypass the cell with the equation in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Word 2010 (possibly 2007) you could check if there is an equation in the cell in this way (this is complete loop for each cell in table which you can easily convert to your needs, Word-VBA code, tried and tested for Word 2010):

```
Dim eqCell As Cell

For Each eqCell In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells

If eqCell.Range.OMaths.Count > 0 Then

    'if there is any equation this if statement will return true
    'so, this cell should be bypassed
    '**EDIT** how to get row and column number of this cell:

    Dim rowNo As Long
    Dim colNo As Long

    rowNo = eqCell.Range.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)
    colNo = eqCell.Range.Information(wdEndOfRangeColumnNumber)

    Debug.Print rowNo, colNo

    '**END OF EDIT**
End If
Next
```

You could try normalize your equation referring to some properties of [OMathFunction Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff846176%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Unfortunately, I have no experience in this area.

**EDIT**

To use this solution within your code you could implement it in few possible ways:

a) to check if there is any equation in the table:

```
If oText.Range.Tables(1).Range.OMath.Count > 0 Then ... '>>here is
```

b) to check if there is equation in your cell:

```
If oText.Range.Tables(1).Cell(r,c).Range.OMath.Count > 0 Then ... '>>here is
```

Comment: I tried running it: it gives me the same error, only from the first cell rather than when the program runs into the equation cell.

Comment: which version of Word Library you use?

Comment: Sorry, I ran it again.  It works, but it won't let me access the Column and Row property of the Cell, because the table has merged cells.  This is a problem because I have to reproduce this table in Excel.

Comment: @Doof12, see two edition of my answer- one within code (as comment), the second- bottom part of the answer.